# FITCKNN with large data sets?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I have some dataset with size of 39366*9 table which I need to apply KNN regression

My problem arises when I use all the data set the MATLAB gives me an error message:

```
Error using bsxfun
Requested 900000000x1 (6.7GB) array exceeds
maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays
greater than this limit may take a long time and
cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array
size limit or preference panel for more
information.
Error in comparison2 (line 81)
S1 =
fitcknn(array2table(X_norm),y,'NumNeighbors',K3,'Standardize',1
```

I have searched this error and found some solution suggesting using tall arrays 
when I tried it this error appears

```
Error using fitcknn (line 247)
FITCKNN does not support tall arrays.
```

My question is, is it possible to use fitcknn with all of this data or should I try something else? if possible how can I do that?

Comment: Have you "See array
size limit or preference panel for more"

Comment: Of Course, I didn't find any useful tips. Only thing I found related to my problem as mentioned in the post

Comment: How much RAM does your computer have? Which MALTAB version are you using?

Comment: 6 GB Ram , 2018b

Comment: So, you are trying to create a matrix bigger than your RAM? Yeah, thats not going to fit. The only solution is tall arrays and yeah, that algorithm does not support them. Unfortunately you are out of luck, this has no solution

Comment: Why do this function request all this array size? is this size for the data set really large?

Comment: Because that is how algorithms work, and particularly, this algorithm. No idea, you'd nee to talk to the developers at mathworks, but I suspect it is as efficient as it can be

Comment: You can convert data type from double to single.

Comment: Converting to single from double and clearing unnecessary variables helps me a bit to use about 20K of the data. But I need more.